# How to show related data together in one diagram?

Tags: info-visualisation

Let us have the following three sets of information

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Now I want to combine all of this data and show it all together. Telling it like a story. Giving inter-relations. Showing similarities in terms, concepts etc. to get the following (Note that in the diagram below, the colored relations may not be exact, they are merely indicative of a node of information)

[image]

**Question:** Is there a good way to do it. Also, Is there a tool available for doing this?

I hope this make the question much more clear. :)

I have posted this question originally on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070150/data-visualisation1.) so you can take a deeper look to understand my question better.

Comment: What is your question?  If you are asking for a program to visualize something, I do not think that you are asking on the right website.

Comment: Rather, I am asking for a solution. Which means that "a way of showing relations" between things

Comment: You need to give us some sample data to understand what you are after. Right now the request is too vague - we could provide charts, graphs, maps, Venn diagrams etc. but without an idea of the data you are trying to show we can only wildly guess.

Comment: The question is unclear. You can edit it. :) I voted for your question because the answers are interesting.

Comment: @JeromeR there you go! :)

Comment: @OrangeRind I modified your question title to be more specific to the actual question asked.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this [one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/953/how-to-display-the-hierarchical-data-closed)

**ADDED:**

and use it with combination of [Topic Map](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/how-to-use-topic-maps) to find out *associations*, *occurrences*(number of occurrences to size "circle") between **topics** (entities).

Comment: this is brilliant!

Comment: now with the updated question, lets wait for some more answers to creep in.

Comment: @OrangeRind I have updated my answer :)

Comment: I think topic maps quite sums up what might be needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to "visualize" relationships between 1 or more things you may find a tool like [this](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/samples) very handy.  Not only does it let you visually build a picture with simple text, but it handles many of the "odd" scenarios that might otherwise be hard to indicate.

[image]

Comment: +1 it is nice, but it is not free tool. :(

Comment: @igor - on the contrary it is! see the FAQ: http://yuml.me/faq "Q: Is it FREE? A:Yup! This site is a free service - enjoy!" The purchase option is only if you want to host it and run it on your own server.